# How can I use cartesian product |@| with latest versions of Cats?

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I've migrated some code using cats 0.2 to cats 0.6, and my code is not wroking anymore :

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.std.all._

val valid1: Validated[List[String], Int] = valid(1)
val valid2: Validated[List[String], Int] = valid(2)
(valid1 |@| valid2).map{_+_}
```

Compiler says :

```
Error:(48, 6) value |@| is not a member of 

cats.data.Validated[List[String],Int]
(valid1 |@| valid2).map{_+_}
    ^
```

I did not find anything in the documentation regarding this, should I had an import or declare an implicit or something?

I've managed to use `product` instead of `|@|` but it's not as convenient as it produces nested tuples. Let's say I have 4 validated to combine :

```
  (valid1 product valid2 product valid3 product valid4)
    .map{case (((v1, v2), v3), v4) => v1 + v2 + v3 + v4}
```

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to import the syntax for applicative builder. cats.syntax.all._ will do it, not sure of the specific import

Comment: @meps thanks it works!

Comment: It is easier to use `import cats.implicits._` then you don't need to search for the correct `cats.std.x` or `cats.syntax.y`  (the specific you needed here was `cats.syntax.cartesian._`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @meps said in comments, missing import was `cats.syntax.all._`

Comment: `|@|` no longer exists. In case it helps anyone, `(ma |@| mb).map` is replaced by `(ma, mb).mapN`.